# Show that a composition operator is not a surjective.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Lets define a composition operator $C_{f}:g \rightarrow g\circ f$ where $f(t) = t^2$. Obviously $C_f:C(0,1) \rightarrow C(-1,1)$ is well-defined and bounded thus cts. Ive been wondering is $C_f$ surjective. I suspect that it isnt since $t^2$ is not surjective on $[-1,1]$. I tried to use definition of surjectivity to show that $C_f$ isnt surjective. So i need to find a function $h \in C(-1,1)$ such that for all $g \in C(0,1)$ holds $h \neq g \circ f$, but without any results. Any help is apperciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $h = g \circ f$, for some $g \in C(0,1)$.  Then for all $0\le x <1$, $h(x) = h(-x)$ because $f$ is symmetric. So consider $\bar{h}(x) = -x$. Is there any such $g$ such that $\bar{h} = g \circ f$?  If not, then $\bar{h}$ doesn't belong to the range of $C_f$.

Comment: For example let $g(t) = -\sqrt{t} \in C(0,1)$ then $\bar{h} = -t$

Comment: @esmegaforceenergydrink If $g(t) = -\sqrt{t}$, then $g \circ f = - \vert t \vert$.  See, for example https://www.desmos.com/calculator/olwsxawaoc.

Comment: Oh i just noticed that also. Well now im trying to find contradiction from an equation $g \circ f = -t$ when $g\in C(0,1)$. Any hints? Intuitively this makes sense.

Comment: @esmegaforceenergydrink  Sure. Suppose, for sake of contradiction, that there exists $g \in C(0,1)$ such that $g \circ f = \bar{h}$.  Pick any point $\hat{t} \in (0,1)$.  Since $f$ is symmetric on $(-1,1)$, $f(\hat{t}) = f(-\hat{t})$.  Thus $g\circ f(\hat{t}) = g\circ f(-\hat{t})$.  But $\bar{h}(t) \neq \bar{h}(-t)$ for any $t \neq 0$.

Comment: Oh yeas obviously im too tired :D Damn i feel stupid.